# spring maven install or clean error, why?

Tags: java, spring, maven, installation

When I use maven `install` or `clean` for my spring project following error occurred.

this problem was occurred in Eclipse 2018-09 version.
when I use eclipse photon version, did not occur this problem.

The error message.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------------<  >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building  1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------    [  war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.442 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-02T23:32:35+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Cannot access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
[ERROR]   roleHint: https
[ERROR] ->     [ Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR]     [ Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Why can't maven `install` or `clean`.

Comment: Are you running maven build behind firewall or proxy? See if you can connect `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` in your browser

Comment: i can see the list my browser.

Comment: Same question. Are you running maven build behind firewall or proxy?

Comment: no..my local env. yesterday that work. but other problem occured, so i remove my .m2 folder and re try maven install.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that this problem occurs when you run Maven with the JDK7.

It worked until April 2019, but then it stopped working failing the Maven build with this error.

Comment: Using Java 8 to run Maven worked for me! Any idea what changed?

Comment: Probably there's a new policy with HTTPS protocol, so the JDK 7 has some issues when it has to download dependencies from Maven repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 uses `TLS v1` as default, so open a terminal and run mvn and specify `TLS v1.2` version:

```
mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 clean install
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791090/not-able-to-build-using-maven-3-6-and-jdk-1-7)